# What are matrixes in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery, github-actions

GitHub released their alternative CI system called Actions. Various workflows from the marketplace, such as [setup-node](https://github.com/actions/setup-node), have "Matrix testing" examples in their README:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-16.04
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node: [ '10', '8' ]
    name: Node ${{ matrix.node }} sample
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm test
```

I used CircleCI before but never stumbled upon this concept. Is it some kind of parallel computation?

Comment: https://github.com/features/actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind a test matrix is that you have several different cases where you want to run exactly the same tests to ensure it works.  For example, I may have a project where I want to test on Node 8 and Node 10 on each of macOS and Linux.

Instead of writing out four jobs, one for each combination of Node version and OS, I can simply write a matrix, write a generic set of steps, and let the tooling create and the four jobs for me.